# Laravel 5.2 and Ratchet Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, ratchet, classnotfound

I am using Ratchet for websockets. It works in general, but I want to use inside my ExampleController Laravels `Auth`. It should be easy but this does not work:

```
<?php namespace Annotation\Http\Controllers;
use Auth;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class ExampleController extends Controller implements MessageComponentInterface {

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
       echo Auth::id();

    //etc.
       echo "New Connection! ({$conn->resourceId})";
    }

}
```

I always get a Class `Auth` not found exception, when I init my Controller in the websocket-server.php (located in the root dir of laravel) file below:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Annotation\Http\Controllers\CollaborativeController;

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new ExampleController(),
    8080
);
$server->run();
```

If I use my ExampleController as a usual controller with a route, the Auth class will be found. (I am also not able to use the auth helper or anything related with laravel)

Why this happens? Because Laravel is not initialized yet or do I need to add path?

Answer (score 0):

The auth function returns an authenticator instance. You may use it instead of the Auth facade for convenience:

```
echo auth()->user()->id;
```

Comment: This won't work, because the helper class and laravels IOC is not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to your server.php if you want to load middlewares.
Auth is a middleware and it's not initialised and loaded.

`require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php'; (set a proper path to your bootstrap)`